# Catching FileFormat property of .XLAM without confusion with .XLSM

Tags: vba

### Context

I have developed a `.xlam` add-in that contains user-data inside. In other words, the user can decide to show the add-in file through a `ThisWorkbook.IsAddIn = False` to edit the content, which is functional to the add-in itself.

*However*, the user should not be able to perform some operations when he's/she's working on the add-in's spreadsheets rather than on the normal workbook where the Add-In is running.

### Need to check for file extension

From here, it comes my need of checking for the file extension and validate it when some specific "forbidden" procedures might get called. I have made the following tests:

- If `ThisWorkbook.IsAddIn = True`, then `ThisWorkbook.FileFormat = 55`;
- If `ThisWorkbook.IsAddIn = False`, then `ThisWorkbook.FileFormat = 52`;

### The source of confusion

This is not what I was expecting. By simply executing a `FullName` request **when the Add-In is set visible**:

```
ThisWorkbook.IsAddIn = False
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

I can read that my file is still named `C:\myFile.xlam`, even if in that moment is visible to the user. So, I would expect `ThisWorkbook.FileFormat` to raise a `55` even if visible at run-time. But it doesn't do that, apparently.

### The question

I need to make sure to distinguish between modifications *on the Add-In (.xlam)* and modifications *on a possible .xlsm file that the user created, from which is using my Add-In*. 
Why is the `FileFormat` of my add-in being equal to the one of an `xlsm`, if the file is clearly `xlam` to which is associated a `55` instead of a `52`? Where am I being wrong?

### EDIT - Example of the action to forbid

On the ribbon there's a button created and added from the add-in, which is connected to a macro that *cannot be run into the Add-In*. So the check I had in mind was something like this:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 55 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

However, as said above, this check will not be performed because the Add-In has `FileFormat = 52` in the moment in which is set to `.IsAddIn = False`; hence, even if the `ActiveWorkbook` is the add-in where I do **not** want to run the macro, the check will fail and the macro will run anyway.

Comment: If the code you want to prevent is running from your add-in then testing for  `ThisWorkbook.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name` wouldn't be sufficient ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, maybe the name property is too weak (user might name the file as the add-in) but you gave me a good input for using `.FullName`, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.IsAddIn` workbook property simply indicates whether the file is being run *as an Add-in*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838249(v=office.14).aspx). It does not change the file format.  From the documentation:

> When you set this property to True, the workbook has the following characteristics:
>
> - You won’t be prompted to save the workbook if changes are made while the workbook is open.
> - The workbook window won’t be visible.
> - Any macros in the workbook won’t be visible in the Macro dialog box (displayed by pointing to Macro on the Tools menu and clicking Macros).
> - Macros in the workbook can still be run from the Macro dialog box even though they’re not visible. In addition, macro names don’t need to be qualified with the workbook name.
> - Holding down the SHIFT key when you open the workbook has no effect.

I sense that this is the real problem you're trying to tackle:

> However, the user should not be able to perform some operations when he's/she's working on the add-in's spreadsheets rather than on the normal workbook where the Add-In is running.

Perhaps it will be best if you can specify what actions you're trying to restrict? There may be a better way to solve this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you got a point when highlighting my real objective. I have edited the body of my question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I think Tim's suggestion in the comment above is probably on the right track. Seems like you can just compare the workbook's `.Name` property, you may *also* need to check the `.IsAddIn` property depending on the specific restrictions/needs, but that should take care of it, no?

Comment: You're right, didn't think about that either! As you can see from my above answer, I have found several solutions for the moment but the real question still stays there: why is the `FileFormat` property changing if the file is still the same? I didn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: No, that's not the "real question", that's only to satisfy your curiosity now that your actual implementation problem has been solved :)  Could be a bug, or it could be by design, i.e., maybe there is some background copy of the file being saved in the other format, temporarily...

Comment: Mmm maybe you're right, if we look at "is the problem solved?" I'd say yes, but this looks a bit buggy to me still. However, bug or design, I will mark your answer since it's the only direct one: "no, the add-in = True doesn't change the file format but it does this, that and this.". But I still think MS lacks of documentation on this point. Thanks a lot

Comment: MS lacks documentation on a lot of things :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the moment I have found four possible solutions, that I'm going to post here just in case someone would have my same issue:

### Comparing the full names - credit to Tim Williams

*The "special code" cannot run if the full names are different*:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.FullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName Then
    Exit Sub
End If
'"special code"
```

### Comparing the isAddIn property - credit to David Zemens

*The "special code" cannot run if this workbook is not currently an add-in*:

```
If ThisWorkbook.IsAddIn = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If
'"special code"
```

### Comparing the two objects

*The "special code" cannot run if the active workbook is the add-in workbook*:

```
If ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then
    Exit Sub
End If 
'"special code"
```

### Checking for "xlam" extension

*The "special" code will not be run if the extension of the file is xlam:*

```
If Right(ActiveWorkbook.FullName,4) = "xlam" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The four solutions above work fine for the purpose, but the question is still opened : *why the `FileFormat` property changes over the same file depending on `ThisWorkbook.IsAddIn` being `False` rather than `True`*?